# Total Count of each subtype and assign to every record again

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I am novice to SQL. I am learning count(). So here is what I am trying to do. There is a table in which Products and Product Types are listed. I want an output which will have a separate column which gives total count of each product_type and assigns it to every record. Can anyone help me to write this query? I searched the forums, but couldn't find similar requirement. Please find attached image for Source table and target table example.

Thank you,
DP

[Case for SQL Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vm0YX.png)

Comment: What did you try? Post the sql query that you tried.

Comment: I highly recommend you to read [this blog](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/index-1429427.html). For your specific problem, see [part 10](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-mar/o23sql-1906475.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use windowed `COUNT`:

```
SELECT Product, 
          Product_Type, 
           COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Product_Type) AS "Count"
FROM table
```